# System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll but was not handled in user code

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I worked with c#(started to work). At first I created model. And by this model I created MVC 5 controller with views, using Entity Framework. I thought that all correct (that necessary table will be created by this model, and I can worked with local database), but when I would like to run my application and go to this page `http://localhost:49640/ControllerName` I get this error:

`Additional information: A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 52 - Unable to locate a Local Database Runtime installation. Verify that SQL Server Express is properly installed and that the Local Database Runtime feature is enabled.)`

I tried to find some solution, but I didn't. As I understood it can be some problems with `connectionStrings` in `Web.config` or some problems with connection to server, but how solve this problem?

My connection strings:

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-MusicApplication-20150620120938.mdf;Initial Catalog=aspnet-MusicApplication-20150620120938;Integrated Security=True"
  providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Comment: Did you add a connection string to your config, or are you just using localdb?

Comment: @PilotBob  I didn't add a connection string manually? i thought, hat it is added 
automatically, it's my connection string:
'<connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-MusicApplication-20150620120938.mdf;Initial Catalog=aspnet-MusicApplication-20150620120938;Integrated Security=True"
      providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>'

Comment: Add the connection string to the question. Did you verify last sentence: **Verify that SQL Server Express is properly installed and that the Local Database Runtime feature is enabled.)**

Comment: Right... it should all be automatic during dev. You didn't by any chance delete that file from app data did you? The view first time you ran the app this happened?

Comment: Are you using Visual Studio? Go to the SQL Sever Object explorer window and add a sql server (LocalDb)\v11.0. If you can't do that, then you don't have localDb enabled or didn't install SQL Express. See if you can run SqlLocalDB.exe in your command window.

Comment: @PilotBob Yes I use VisualStudio 2013. And when I go to server explorer and click SQL Server Object Explorer, I have an error. What this mean, I can reinstall Sql Server?

Comment: What about opening a command window and typing SqlLocalDb?

Comment: You use default install options when you install VS 2013. And you have all the updates installed? Not sure why you get and error opening the SQL Server Object Explorer window. What's the error?

Comment: thanks, I solved this problem. install  SqlLocalDB. this article: [link](http://jaryl-lan.blogspot.com/2014/08/localdb-connection-to-localdb-failed.html) helped me

Comment: GLad you got it worked out. Sometimes the error message really do tell you what the problem is. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I download SqlLocalDb and installed it, this solve my problem. This link [connection to local db failed 52](http://jaryl-lan.blogspot.com/2014/08/localdb-connection-to-localdb-failed.html) helped me.